# require(...) is not a function ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to host my website which uses expressJS on my raspberry PI. I get this error, I don't know what to do especially since this isn't my code.

`TypeError: require(...) is not a function at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:16:29) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18) at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:16:13) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)`

My Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
console.log('required express');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');

let domain = require('domain')
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    var reqd = domain.create();
    domain.active = reqd;
    reqd.add(req);
    reqd.add(res);
    reqd.on('error', function(err) {
      req.next(err);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log('disposing domain for url ' + req.url);
      reqd.dispose();
    });
    reqd.run(next);
})

app.get('/public/styles.css', (req, res) => { res.sendFile('/home/pi/RSite/styles.css')

})

app.get('/public/navbar.js', (req, res) => { res.sendFile('/home/pi/RSite/navbar.js')

})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/home');
})

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.send(readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8'));
})

app.get('/forum', (req, res) => {
    res.send(readFileSync('forum.html', 'utf-8'))
})

app.get('/project', (req, res) => {
    res.send(readFileSync('project.html', 'utf-8'))
})

app.get('/videos', (req, res) => {
    res.send(readFileSync('videos.html', 'utf-8'))
})

app.get('/other', (req, res) => {
    res.send(readFileSync('other.html', 'utf-8'))
})

let port = 49481; // this is the only open port on my IP

console.log('listening on port ' + port);
app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {"Listening on port " + port}); // I use an actual IP address, that isn't the error.
```

What's even more strange is that it works on my laptop, but not on the raspberry pi.
What should I do?

Comment: how does your package.json file look? Does this link answer your question? https://flaviocopes.com/is-not-a-function/

Answer (score 0):

I had an old version of Node.js that was listed as stable, so I updated it.
Works fine now.